# How do I dim a UITableViewCell's cell.backgroundView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my table, I'm currently setting the background of the cells as an image like so:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
```

However, the white text that overlays this image in the cell is hard to read, so I'd like to add a dimming effect to it.

As far as I know, the closest thing that's available is `UIBlurEffectStyleLight`, but this blurs rather than dims, and the blur effect is too strong, making the image barely visible. Is there a way to dim it instead?

Comment: did you try altering the alpha?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add a UIView between the image and the text, then give it a black background colour and set its alpha to like 0.3 or an appropriate amount

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the alpha of the imageView

```
cell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.5; //Alpha runs from 0.0 to 1.0
```